# Prevent fetch request if browser session variable exists

Tags: javascript, session-variables, conditional-operator

I have a function that pulls the users location based on an API request and stores it as a session variable in the browser. Then, it gets the phone number based on the users location which is stored in the session variable. However, I'm trying to prevent the fetch requests from being made if the browser has the session variable stored, to prevent unnecessary API requests.

I'd tried checking if the `country_code` variable exists in the session storage, but that seems to lock up the subsequent requests:

```
async function fetchCountryAndPhone() {
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("country_code")) {
        const [countryCode, phoneNum] = await Promise.all([
          fetch('/userinfo/'),
          fetch('/contacts/')
        ]);
        const country = await countryCode.json();
        sessionStorage.setItem("country_code", country.country_code.toLowerCase())
    }
    const phone = await phoneNum.json();
    return [phone];
}

fetchCountryAndPhone().then(([phone]) => {
        let getCountryCode = sessionStorage.getItem("country_code");
        let getContactNum = phone[`${getCountryCode}`].sales
        ....

    }).catch(error => console.warn(error));
```

How can I adjust the logic to prevent subsequent fetch requests if the `country_code` session variable exists, and just use the one that's already been stored?

Comment: If you skip the `fetch()`, you won't set `phoneNum`, so how will you do `phone = await phoneNum.json()`?

Comment: @Barmar - That's another issue. So how can I gate the request so that it doesn't fire more than the initial page load, that subsequent page loads will look at the session variable value and I'd need to store the phone contacts object as well to reference in order to prevent the need for a phone API request as well?

Answer (score 0):

Save both `country_code` and `phone` in session storage.

```js
async function fetchCountryAndPhone() {
  if (!sessionStorage.getItem("country_code")) {
    const [countryCode, phoneNum] = await Promise.all([
      fetch('/userinfo/'),
      fetch('/contacts/')
    ]);
    const country = await countryCode.json();
    sessionStorage.setItem("country_code", country.country_code.toLowerCase());
    const phone = await phoneNum.json();
    sessionStorage.setItem("phone", JSON.stringify(phone));
  }
  let phone = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("phone"));
  return [phone];
}
```

Comment: I think this is closer, but `/userinfo` appears to still be getting called

Comment: Then something must be clearing the session storage.